# Likelihood Ratio Test for uniform distribution

Tags: self-learning, uniform-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I'm doing self-study here, and have a question about the LRT for uniform distribution.

$X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d $\operatorname{Uniform}(0, \theta)$

$H_0: \theta = \theta_0 = 1$
$H_1: \theta < 1$

What I tried so far:

$$\lambda(\theta) = \frac{\prod(X_{(n)} < 
\theta_0)}{\theta^{-n} \prod(X_{(n)} < \theta)}$$

**How to deal with the product of the indicate function here?**

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $\prod (X_{(n)}<\theta_0)$?

Comment: Since this uniform support depends on the parameter, I suppose I should write it out explicitly.

Comment: That $\lambda(\theta)$ is not related LRT, I think.

Comment: What do you mean by '$\lambda(\theta)$ is not related LRT' here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MLE under the alternative hypothesis is $X_{(n)}$.

The MLE under the null hypothesis is $1,$ since that is the only number in the parameter space if the null hypothesis is true.

Therefore the numerator in $\lambda(\theta)$ is $1.$ You have
$$
\lambda(\theta) = \begin{cases} \dfrac 1 {\theta^{-n}} = \theta^n & \text{if } X_{(n)} \le \theta\le 1, \\  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$

Comment: I guess the test statistic should be $(X_{(n)})^n$?

Comment: @WhiteBig : Correct. $\qquad$

Comment: The product in the numerator is simple incorporated into the support of $X_{(n)}$, right? The product in the denominator will be showed as the support, right?

Comment: I don't understand your last question.

Comment: Okay, I see it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note that any monotone function of the test statistic can also be used as the test statistic.  Suppose you reject NH if $(X_{(n)})^n < a.$ That's the same as rejecting if $X_{(n)} < b,$ where $b = a^{1/n}.$ So you can use $X_{(n)}$ as the test statistic provided you use $b$ rather than $a$ as the critical value.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and that sort of thing is often done for the purpose of getting a simpler expresion as the test statistic.

Comment: Got you,that usually simplify the calculation. Thanks for pointing out that.